# table layout different sizes for different screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have some buttons I want to order in a table layout and everything is working fine, but of course a tablet screen is much bigger than a normal smartphone screen. So I wonder if it is possible to reorder a table for the size of the screen the device have. Otherwise there is so much space unused.
I made a picture to explain my problem:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4018/yeq9crpt_jpg.htm

So as you can see I have a lot of buttons and also a scrollable view with the table layout. Can I change the table rows so it uses the whole screen for both devices (smartphone and tablet) ?

This is how it should look like:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4018/zkbconie_jpg.htm

I really hope you can help me with this. That would be great.

Comment: Don't use TableLayout on Android. Use a RelativeLayout to achieve the same effect, or a GridView if the number of buttons is variable. A GridView is most likely what you'll need. The code will be easier to maintain in the long-run if you use a GridView.

Comment: O.k. but when I use the Grid Layout I also have to set columns and rows right? So I have the same problem here or did I miss something?

Comment: Do your buttons really need to remain square? You can do a layout for portrait mode and one for landscape mode. Or you could even be much more precise by specifying the minimum width for your larger layout. Someone can explain to you how to do that. I don't have the time right now.